# PythonException: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'NoneType' and 'int''

Tags: python, function, pyspark

I have this function which converts seconds to dd:hh:mm:ss (string) - however, when there is a null instance from the input column, I receive the error PythonException: 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for divmod(): 'NoneType' and 'int''.

is there a fix that can be put inside the function, below -

```
  def to_hms(s):
 m, s = divmod(s, 60)
 h, m = divmod(m, 60)
 d, h = divmod(h, 24)
 return '{}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(d, h, m, s)
```

Comment: "when there is a null instance from the input column" what does that mean, **exactly**? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Hmm, I don't immediately see a problem with your function, unless s is None when the function is called. Could you provide some of your calling code too?

Comment: There's not enough of a [mcve] to be able to answer. Simplest would be `try: except:`, or some validation before you run your function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can help:

```
def to_hms(s):
    if s:
        m, s = divmod(s, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)
        d, h = divmod(h, 24)
        return '{}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}:{:0>2}'.format(d, h, m, s)
    return '0:00:00:00'
```

This one will return empty value if it does not find value for s.

Comment: Great, worked exactly how needed; thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!